# What's this serialised comic strip about a girl who discovers everyone around her is a robot?

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots

As a kid in the '80s, I found myself often in doctor's waiting rooms. I devoured most of the comic magazines there. In one of those, I read fragments of a story that I would like to find.

The story was set in (then) current time. The protagonist was a teen girl, who discovered that people around her had been replaced by robots. These robots' faces could hinge upwards, revealing gears behind them.
I remember her looking in the mirror and even seeing her *own* face hinging upwards to reveal herself being a robot, however, that may have been a dream.

As I recall, in the end it was revealed some catastrophe had happened, perhaps a nuclear bomb, and "someone" (perhaps benevolent aliens) had replaced her loved ones for her. I think it ended with her reliving the final moments of her old world, knowing what was about to happen.

---

This was in The Netherlands and the story was written in Dutch, although it may have been translated.

The story was serialised, 2 or perhaps 4 pages at a time, which is why I've only read fragments.

- The most likely magazine I've read this in was a Dutch girls' magazine called *[Tina](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tina_(tijdschrift))*. <sup><sub>*(Dutch Wikipedia)*</sub></sup>
  Most comics in it were about girls overcoming some obstacle to pursue their dream — usually horse riding or ice skating, finding love in the process — which is what would've made this story stand out. Another such magazine was called *Debbie*.
- Another likely source is comics magazine *[Eppo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eppo_(comics))*, later called *Eppo Wordt Vervolgd*, that featured serialised comics.
- Yet another possible source is *[Taptoe](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taptoe_(tijdschrift))*. <sup><sub>*(Dutch Wikipedia)*</sub></sup>, a weekly and later biweekly magazine that was distributed through schools/ It had sister publications *Okki* and *Jippo*, but those were aimed at smaller children and this story must've been too mature for them.

The style as I remember it resembles *[ligne claire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligne_claire)*, known from the Franco-Belgian comics known as *bandes dessinée*. It may also have been a realistic drawing style. It was definitely in colour.